# Menu not updated after role purchase

Tags: routes, ubercart, caching, users

after a user purchases a certain role (i use UC and a rule to do so) the main menu is not updated automatically. The user had access to everything that belongs to the new role, but the menu only gets updated when i manually clear the cache on the site. 
In searching for a solution i found this has to do with menu caching. 
I don't use drush or devel and need a solution that suits a production site. Is it best to completely disable menu caching? And how do i do that? Is there a module for that? 
Thanx,
Cas

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable menu cache - if you could, Drupal would need to scan all modules on every request and it would kill your site. You can use [Cache Actions](https://drupal.org/project/cache_actions):

> It currently provides actions for:
>
> - Clearing Drupal cache bins
> - Clearing CSS/JS cache
> - Clearing The cache of specific views
> - Clearing The cache of specific panel pages
> - Clearing The cache of specific mini panels

Just clear menu cache in the same rule you use to add a role to your user. After adding that role, of course.

Comment: Any clues on which action to use? I tried cache bins and "cache" as its value, but that doesn't work. There doesn't seem to be a value for menu cache. Also, menu rules (another module i found) lacks an action to clear menu cache.

Comment: @caskraker You are using Drupal 7?

Comment: Yes. I found a way to enter PHP in an action, by enabling the core module PHP filter. But cache_clear_all('*', 'cache_menu', TRUE); doesn't have any effect. Some other PHP string i can use?

Comment: In D7 it can be a problem as this module is in alpha stage.